# Удалить первую ссылку HTML

Tags: javascript

Как удалить первую ссылку в HTML с помощью JavaScript?
Думаю нужно выбрать первый элемент  и удалить его, помогите с кодом.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].remove()
```

Comment: можно также просто `document.querySelector('a').remove()`